# What is an az2z zip?

Tags: file-upload, configuration, akamai

Configuring remote file storage account (on Akamai) and there is an `allow/do not allow az2z zip uploads` - searched through all their documentation and checked everywhere else I though that would be sequitur, as well as searched for it and can't find `az2z zip` defined anywhere. Anybody have an idea what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just from recall of using Akamai back in 2006/2007.*

az2z was a command that would index zip files. 
After indexing the cdn would then be able to directly address files within the zip file.

The intention was that the files where not expanded after they were uploaded, but that they could efficiently perform an offset and expand of the file of interest from within the zip file when requested.